# On a proof of Kronecker-Weber Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, dedekind-domain

There is a proof of Kronecker-Weber theorem which I cannot understand (in fact I have been asking questions on several steps of the proof, and here is another one).

There is the following proposition:

> Let $p\in \mathbb{N}$ be an odd prime. Then there is a unique extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ of order $p$ such that its discriminant is a power of $p$.

The proof of the proposition is postponed and it proceeds to prove a particular case (which imply the general case by some other arguments which are not important right now):

> **Theorem.** Let $p$ be an odd prime in $\mathbb{N}$ and let $K/\mathbb{Q}$ be a cyclic extension of degree $p^n$ whose discriminant is a power of $p$ is contained in $\mathbb{Q}\left (\zeta\right )$, where $\zeta=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{p^{n+1}}}$.
>
> *Proof.* Let $L$ be the unique subfield of $\mathbb{Q}\left (\zeta\right )$ of order $p^n$. Then $KL$ is an extension whose order is a power of $p$.
>
> $\text{Gal}\left (L/\mathbb{Q}\right )$ is cyclic, let $\tau$ be a generator and let $\sigma$ be any automorphism of $KL$ extending $\tau$. Let $F$ be the fixed field of $<\sigma >$. Then $L\cap F=\mathbb{Q}$, and there is an injection $\text{Gal}\left (LK/\mathbb{Q}\right )\to \text{Gal}\left (L/\mathbb{Q}\right )\times \text{Gal}\left (K/\mathbb{Q}\right )$ which has exponent $p^n$, so $\sigma$ has order at most $p^n$, but since it extended an element having order $p^n$, $\sigma$ has order exactly $p^n$. We will show that $[FL:F]=p^n$, hence $KL=FL$, and that $FL\subset \mathbb{Q}\left (\zeta\right )$, hence $K\subset \mathbb{Q}\left (\zeta\right )$.
>
> If $F\neq \mathbb{Q}$ then both $L$ and $F$ contain the unique cyclic extension of degree $p$ with discriminant a power of $p$. This contradicts $L\cap F=\mathbb{Q}$. Thus $FL=L\subset \mathbb{Q}\left (\zeta\right )$ and $[FL:L]=[L:L\cap F]=[L:\mathbb{Q}]=p^n$. $\blacksquare$

I understood everything except the following: *If $F\neq \mathbb{Q}$ then both $L$ and $F$ contain the unique cyclic extension of degree $p$ with discriminant a power of $p$.*

Why is that true? It is true that $L$ has a subfield of order $p$ and therefore it must have discriminant a power of $p$ since it is a subextension of $\mathbb{Q}\left (\zeta\right )$, whose discriminant is a power of $p$.

If we were able to show that the same holds for $F$, then the uniqueness would give us the result, but I cannot see why it is true. I suspect that $F\subset K$ (and it trivially impies what we want) but I am not very convinced.

Comment: $F$ is a subextension of $KL$, which by construction has order a power of $p$. So $F$ is a Galois extension of $\mathbb Q$ whose order is a power of $p$.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand why $F$ has degree a power of $p$. What we do know is that $KL/F$ has degree a power of $p$.

Comment: Also, we have to prove that $F$ has discriminant a power of $p$. If I were able to prove that $F\subset K$ I would be done, but maybe it is not true.

Comment: The point is to prove that $F$ is trivial, so that $KL=L$. $KL/\mathbb Q$ has order a power of $p$, and $F$ is just a subextension. So it’s order is a power of $p$, and hence $F$ is either trivial or it contains a subfield of order $p$.

Comment: Now use the fact that $F\subset \mathbb Q(\zeta)$

Comment: Yes, sorry, it was trivial that $F$ had degree a power of $p$. But why $F\subset \mathbb{Q}\left (\zeta\right )$?

Comment: Because $FL\subset\mathbb Q(\zeta)$

Comment: That's exactly what we want to prove. Indeed, the proof makes use of the fact that $F$ has discriminant a power of $p$ in order to show that $FL\subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta)$, so your argument is not valid. But finally I could prove it by myself: since every prime which isn't ramified in both $L$ and $K$ is also unramified in $LK$ (and so in every sub-extension) then we also have that the only ramified prime in $F$ is $p$, therefore its discriminant is a power of $p$.